# Stop form post on page load

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-webpages

I have a search function which works. It searches for registered users, it works when you search only for their partial username, however, the problem with this is that when you load the page, it basically searches, but the search-string is empty, which means it returns every user. I need to make it so it only searches when you actually search. But I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. I guess basically I need to stop the form from posting on page load.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Admin/_SiteLayout.cshtml";

    var db = Database.Open("MikZeRCoding2");
    var userSearchQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE UserName LIKE '%' + @0 + '%'";

    var UsernameSearch = "";
    var ErrorMessage = "";
    Validation.RequireField("search-username", "lel");

    if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid()) {
        UsernameSearch = Request.Form["search-username"];

        if (UsernameSearch.IsEmpty()) {
            ErrorMessage = "You didn't search for anything.";
        }

        if (!UsernameSearch.IsEmpty() && db.QueryValue(userSearchQuery, UsernameSearch) == null) {
            ErrorMessage = "No results for '" + UsernameSearch + "' were found...";
        }

        else {

        }
    }
}

<div class="search-users">
    <h2>Search users</h2>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="search-username" placeholder="Search for a user" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="button"></button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />

        @foreach(var user in db.Query(userSearchQuery, UsernameSearch)) {
            <a href="@Href("~/Admin/Accounts/User", user.UserId)"><span>[ @user.UserId ]</span>  @user.UserName</a>
        }
        @if(!ErrorMessage.IsEmpty()) {
            <div class="alert alert-danger">@ErrorMessage</div>
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
        }
    </form>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, when the page loads, your back end code follows a code path which loads all users?  If so, can you provide the back end code?

Comment: It's the above code, the C# code. I think it's just the form which posts itself when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your view of the users in a `IsPost`-statement;

```
@if(IsPost){
    foreach(var user in db.Query(userSearchQuery, UsernameSearch)) {
        <a href="@Href("~/Admin/Accounts/User", user.UserId)"><span>[ @user.UserId ]</span>  @user.UserName</a>
    }
}
```